# VSCode Maven error `The compiler compliance specified is 1.7 but a JRE 13 is used`

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I created a new maven project in VSCode.  When I try to run a file, I get this error

`The compiler compliance specified is 1.7 but a JRE 13 is used`

but there are no instructions on how to fix the error.  What do I do?

These are the VSC plugins I have installed:

- Debugger for Java 0.25.0
- Java Dependency Viewer 0.9.0
- Java Extension Pack 0.8.1
- Java Run 1.1.4
- Java Test Runner 0.22.0

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial Install a JDK.  TLDR; Install Visual Studio.  After installing the JDK, you would need to configure your environment for Java development. The most common way is to set JAVA_HOME environment variable to the install location of the JDK while you can also use java.home setting in Visual Studio Code settings (workspace or user settings) to configure it just for the editor.

Comment: How do I get the install location of JDK?  I already installed it but I did not write down the folder location and when I search my mac for JDK there are no results.

Comment: Reinstall and pay attention this time.  It should be something  like /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10. jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Try to find in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`,you should reinstall the jdk

Comment: If, unlike the original poster, you are seeing a similar error in the context of [Spring Boot][1] with the [Spring Initializer][2], be sure to select your matching `Java` (version) before generating your Spring Boot project.

  [1]: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot
  [2]: https://start.spring.io/

Comment: @Cody open Terminal and run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` you will get the location of JDK on your Mac

Answer (score 23):

To solve this problem, you have to update manually the pom.xml file. Everything you have to do is explained in the [doc, section "Java 9 or later"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html#java-9-or-later). Here are the steps to follow.

The default pom.xml file provide theses informations:

**Old version - pom.xml**

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.0</version>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

As you can see, Maven uses an outdated plugin to be used with maven.compiler.source for Java 1.7. Here you want to update the plugin an specify the use of Java 13. Modify pom.xml like so:

**New solution version - pom.xml**

```xml
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.release>13</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Now don't forget to update VSCode configutation by right-clicking on the pom.xml file then click on `Update Project Configuration` or do `Alt+Shift+U` and wait for the change to apply.

Normally, the PROBLEMS section should be `No problems have been detected in the workspace so far.`

Comment: Using Java 11, and this solution worked for a an IntelliJ project I opened with VS Code.

Comment: To update this, using 13 just changed the error to not able to support v13 in vscode. Changing maven compiler release to 17 resolved the issue on my end

Answer (score 10):

my problem was similar but with JDK11 and JDK14

In my case, I changed the version in the pom.xml, like @Onyr said, but the problem kept popping up. To fix it I followed these steps:

1. In VSCode, press `Crtl + Shift + P`. This will show a popup when you can write
2. Then write `>Configure Java runtime` (Make sure not to delete the character `>`)
3. Click the first result to open the configure window
4. In my case, I saw this:

[image]

As you can see, the current path point to JDK14, but I want to use JDK11

5. So, click in `User Setting` (Blue link in "Type" column)
6. Then, click in `Edit in settings.json`
7. Now, you have to search a property called `"java.home"` and change the path to the JDK you want to use

For example, in my case, this line changed from:

```
"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-14.0.2",
```

To:

```
"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.8",
```

8. Finally, VSCode will show a popup asking you to restart the config. Do it and the problem go